# USB Drive Password when copying data

Tags: usb, usb-drive, usb-device

Is there a possible way or software where I can still be able to save files to my USB Drive but it will require password when I copy a file from my USB Drive to another computer?

I tried write-protecting the drive but even saving files to my USB Drive won't work.

What I wanted to do is to let anyone save any file to my USB Drive, but when they copy something from my USB Drive, they will be required with a password.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to create VeraCrypt encrypted container.

https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/

If you have any question regarding VeraCrypt, please comment.

Comment: I will try this now.